# can we pass data from table cell to table view where both are xib files?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xib

I want to pass table cell data (xib file) to table view (also a xib file). I have tried passing the data using the following piece of code but did not get an appropriate result.

**PropertyCell.swift**

```
    import UIKit

    class PropertyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var propertyCodeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLbl: UILabel!

    }
```

I have attached the screenshot for PropertyCell below -

**PropertyCell.xib**

[PropertyCell.xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhGQR.png)

**PropertyTableVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PropertyTableVC: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet var propertyTabel: UITableView!

    let URL_Landlord_Property_List = "http://127.0.0.1/source/api/LandlordPropertyList.php"
    var count: Int = 0
    var landlordPropertyArray: [PropertyList]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
        propertyTabel.dataSource = self
        propertyTabel.delegate = self

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "PropertyCell", bundle:nil)
        self.propertyTabel.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    func fetchData(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL_Landlord_Property_List)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            print(data!)
            self.landlordPropertyArray = [PropertyList]()
            self.count = (self.landlordPropertyArray?.count)!
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let datafromjson = json["landlords_property_list"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    print(datafromjson)
                    for data in datafromjson{
                        var property = PropertyList()
                        if let id = data["ID"] as? Int,let code = data["Code"] as? String, let address1 = data["Address"] as? String
                        {
                            property.id = id
                            property.code = code
                            property.address1 = address1

                        }
                        self.landlordPropertyArray?.append(property)
                    }
                    print(self.landlordPropertyArray)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.propertyTabel.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (landlordPropertyArray?.count)!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PropertyCell
        cell.propertyCodeLbl.text = self.landlordPropertyArray?[indexPath.item].code
        cell.addressLbl.text = self.landlordPropertyArray?[indexPath.item].address1
        return cell
    } 
}
```

Attached the screenshot for Property Table below -

**PropertyTableVC.xib**

[PropertyTableVC.xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA37c.png)

Comment: did you try creating a Protocol ?

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { self.propertyTabel.reloadData() } --> Add this code inside the if let datafromjson = ..... {}

Comment: @AshishBahl No I have not tried protocols as I have not used it before. Can you please give me dummy example to use it?

Comment: @BoominadhaPrakashM Thank you. I made the changes as you said but there is no change.

Comment: check my answer @Saurabh

Comment: I'll take a look to your answer @AshishBahl

Comment: sure @Saurabh let me know if that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Call         `fetchData()` function after tableview delegate and datasource assigning

```
        propertyTabel.dataSource = self
        propertyTabel.delegate = self
```

Updated answer is 
Create Cell Class like this

```
import UIKit

class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeDateLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.tableViewBackgroundColor()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

class func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> YourTableViewCell {
    let kYourTableViewCell = "YourTableViewCellIdentifier"
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"RRLoadQuestionsTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: kYourTableViewCell)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kYourTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

    return cell

}
```

}

Then create UIViewController Class and place UITableView on it and link with outlet

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var dataSource =  [LoadYourData]()

// MARK: - Init & Deinit

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViewControllerUI()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(true)

}

// MARK: - UIViewController Helper Methods

func setupViewControllerUI() {

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self
    loadData()

}

func loadData() {

// Write here your API and reload tableview once you get response
}


// MARK: - UITableView Data Source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = YourTableViewCell.cellForTableView(tableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)

 // assign here cell.name etc from dataSource
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I made the changes as you mentioned in the above code but the table is not getting populated.

Comment: Is you getting response from server?

Comment: Yes, I got the response from server but it is not getting populated in the table view.

Comment: Is tableView reloadData is calling after getting response from server?. Debug your tableview datasource after getting response from server.

Comment: I tried this @Josh but it is showing the same output problem

Comment: the issue is with your cell. your cell is not loading correctly.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is. I am getting the json data in array but why the cell is not able to receive it.

Comment: I have created a xib file of UITableView and on my storyboard View Controller there is only one view i.e. UIScrollView. On that scroll view, I want to display my tableview with its cells

Comment: then too I will try your above code and let you know. Thanks Josh

Answer (score 0):

Your TableViewCell :

```
import UIKit

protocol yourProtocolName { //add protocol here
func getDataFromTableViewCellToViewController (sender : self) //* as you need to pass the table view cell, so pass it as self
}

    class PropertyCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var propertyCodeLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var addressLbl: UILabel!
        var delegate : yourProtocolName? //set a delegate

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            if delegate != nil {
                delegate.getDataFromTableViewCellToViewController(sender :self) *
        }
    }
}
```

And your ViewController :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PropertyTableVC: UITableViewController,yourProtocolName { //conform to the protocol you created in tableViewCell


    @IBOutlet var propertyTabel: UITableView!

    let URL_Landlord_Property_List = "http://127.0.0.1/source/api/LandlordPropertyList.php"
    var count: Int = 0
    var landlordPropertyArray: [PropertyList]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
        propertyTabel.dataSource = self
        propertyTabel.delegate = self

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "PropertyCell", bundle:nil)
        self.propertyTabel.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    func fetchData(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL_Landlord_Property_List)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            print(data!)
            self.landlordPropertyArray = [PropertyList]()
            self.count = (self.landlordPropertyArray?.count)!
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let datafromjson = json["landlords_property_list"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    print(datafromjson)
                    for data in datafromjson{
                        var property = PropertyList()
                        if let id = data["ID"] as? Int,let code = data["Code"] as? String, let address1 = data["Address"] as? String
                        {
                            property.id = id
                            property.code = code
                            property.address1 = address1

                        }
                        self.landlordPropertyArray?.append(property)
                    }
                    print(self.landlordPropertyArray)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.propertyTabel.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (landlordPropertyArray?.count)!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PropertyCell
        cell.propertyCodeLbl.text = self.landlordPropertyArray?[indexPath.item].code
        cell.addressLbl.text = self.landlordPropertyArray?[indexPath.item].address1
        return cell
    } 

    func getDataFromTableViewCellToViewController(sender :UITableViewCell) {
        //make a callback here
    }
}
```

(*) Marked fields are updated code

Comment: how can I call a protocol here?

Comment: @Saurabh I displayed it in my answer. See the code carefully I have mentioned it within comments

Comment: Yes! I found it. So I will make the necessary changes and re-run the code. If it works I'll definitely let you know. Thanks @AshishBahl

Comment: The code you provided is showing me this error -> `var delegate : cellProtocol ?

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            if delegate != nil {
                delegate.getDataFromTableViewCellToViewController(sender :UITableViewCell) // Show error on UITableViewCell 
        }
    }

**ERROR** : Cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewCell.Type' to expected argument type 'UITableViewCell'`

Comment: I modified my answer @Saurabh

Comment: I made the changes and the error got resolved but now what should I write in my Table View Controller where you have commented "// make a callback here". As I have not used the protocol concept before, please help.

Comment: whatever functionality you require you do it there @Saurabh